# Prevent connection to a slot ("Really" private slots)

Tags: c++, qt

Using Qt I know that `private slots` means the slot is private when called directly but a `connect()` can still allow a signal to be connected to a slot whether private, public, or I guess, protected.

So, is there a way to make a slot really private, such that only a connection within a class can be done? What I am thinking here is because of the `QTimer::singleShot` that calls a slot but the function I want to call I don't want to be accessible outside of the class. I am sure there are other reasons but this is the main one at the moment I have found.

Comment: Who cares if it's private or not? Are you afraid some evil guys will try to call that on purpose?

Comment: @BlaXpirit I appreciate the comment. Perhaps it is a tad OCD of me but I like to remove any possibility of mistake where possible and i felt it would be good programming practice. It isn't about people calling on purpose, it is about preventing people doing it by accident and reducing the possibility of bugs. Also, I am curious as to if it is possible. Always good to try and learn new techniques i think :-)

Comment: Unfortunately all of this is moot anyways because if you *really* wanted to access a private member, you could `#define private public` before calling it. As for this specific problem, private/public/protected access is a compile-time feature of C++, and signals/slots are a run-time feature, by which time the concept of public and private does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to enforce this, and you dont think proper documentation will solve this issue, add the slot to a extra class, which has a private constructor and relays the call to your real class.

```
class PrivateSlotClass : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
friend class YourRealClass;
PrivateSlotClass( YourRealClass ) : QObject( YourRealClass ){}
private slots:
  void theSlot(){ static_cast<YourRealClass*>(parent())->theFunction();
};

class YourRealClass : public QObject
{
public:
   YourRealClass();
friend class PrivateSlotClass;
private:
 void theFunction();
};

YourRealClass::YourRealClass(){ 
    PrivateSlotClass* myPrivateSlot = new PrivateSlotClass(this);
    QTimer::singleShot( 50, myPrivateSlot, SLOT(theSlot()) );
}
void YourRealClass::theFunction()
{
/* your slot code here */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. I do take on board what you said in your text about documentation and to be honest that is more likely what I would do as the way around it is too much work for little  benefit. hhowever I find this of interest from a theoretical point of view.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [timerEvent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#timerEvent) and [startTimer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#startTimer) instead of slot and QTimer::singleShot.

Comment: +1. Don't use `slots` if you don't want the API to be public (via metaobject). [link](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/3610)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible to add one more argument to your slot and corresponding signal like this:

```
...
private slots:
    void slot(..., QObject* sender = 0);
...

void YourClass::slot(..., QObject* sender)
{
    if (sender != (QObject*)this)
    {
        /* do nothing or raise an exception or do whatever you want */
    }
    ...
}
```

Of course it won't make your slot 'completely' private, but it won't let your code to be executed after receiving a signal from the outside of your object.

Comment: QObject has a `sender()` function that would obviate the need for the additional parameter, or the possibility of someone just spoofing the parameter.

Comment: This doesn't allow one instance of the class to send a signal to another instance of the class, so it's actually more restrictive than private.